# How to caculate/estimate Gas Limit and Gas Price based on current state of the ether network?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, gas-price, gas-estimate

[Ethgasstation](https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php) and similar websites estimate proper Gas Price based on current state of Ethereum network. Is there any way of using working with `Geth`/`web3` to estimate proper Gas Price? and similar to this, how about estimate Gas Limit?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getBlock` on the latest block in Web3 to get back the gas limit of that block:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getblock

> `gasLimit` - `Number`: The maximum gas allowed in this block.

You are probably pretty safe to use that gas limit on the next transaction you want to create.

Web3 also has a gas price oracle as documented here:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getgasprice

> Returns the current gas price oracle. The gas price is determined by
>   the last few blocks median gas price.